# Python replacing all list elements instead of the indexed list element in for loop

Tags: python, list

I want to replace the kth element of the kth element of the list.

E.g.,

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

to

```
[[1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1]]
```

BUT python does not seem to want to do that and instead is replacing each value for each element.

I run this:

```
    # Triangle Vertices
    V = [[0, 1], [-1, 0], [1, 0]]
    
    # Triangles (indices of V in clockwise direction)
    T = [[1, 0, 2]]
    
    # Creating sub-triangles
    bary_point = [0, 0.5]
    
    v_list = []
    
    for t in T:
        print(t)
        for k in range(3):
            v_list.append(V)
            v_list[k][k] = bary_point # <-- This line
    
    print('v_list: ')
    print(v_list)
```

and it produces this:

```
v_list:
[[[0, 0.5], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.5]],
 [[0, 0.5], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.5]],
 [[0, 0.5], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.5]]]
```

**but** I want this:

```
v_list:
[[[0, 0.5], [-1, 0],  [1, 0]],
 [[0, 1],   [0, 0.5], [1, 0]],
 [[0, 1],   [-1, 0],  [0, 0.5]]]
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am on Python 3.10.0

Thank you.

Comment: You have multiple references *to the same list* in `v_list`, i.e., you placed the list referenced by `v` in `v_list` 3 times. Consider, `row = [0, 0]; data = [row, row, row]; data[0][0] = 99; print(data, row)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could I perhaps do this in a one line for loop? Like `v_list = [ v for v in V]`? I will try your recommendation first though thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the same reference to the list `V`, and when you change `v_list[k][k]` you are changing `V`, one solution would be to append a copy of the list, by using `V.copy()` as argument to `append`.